# ManagementBaseObject not found

Tags: c#, .net

Hi I'm having a problem implementing this method.

I have added using System.Management but the class still doesn't work.

The error is:

> Error 7 The type or namespace name 'ManagementBaseObject' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: which IDE are you using. you may flag your entry appropriately to your IDE

Comment: I'm using MS Visual Studio 2010

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You are probably missing the assembly reference to System.Management.dll.  The `using` statement just brings names into scope, to save you typing the prefix: it doesn't actually add a DLL reference.

Right-click your project's References folder and choose Add Reference.  Go to the .NET tab of the resulting dialog, select System.Management and click OK.

Comment: I can't use using System.Management.dll.

Only using System.Management.Instrumentation

Comment: What do you see when you go into the Add Reference dialog, .NET tab?  Is System.Management not there?  Greyed out?

Comment: Yes System.Management is there but I can't see or use System.Management.dll

Comment: That's fine.  The Add Reference dialog just isn't showing the .dll extension (because everything in the list is a DLL so it would be a waste of space).  Click System.Management in the dialog box, and click OK.

Comment: Weird, that should work.  I think you'd better post a code fragment and a screenshot of your References folder so we can see what's going on.

Answer (score 2):

did you add `System.Management.dll` as a reference?

[msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.managementbaseobject.aspx) tells us more about where to find `ManagementBaseObject`:

> Namespace:  System.Management
>   Assembly:  System.Management (in
>   System.Management.dll)

Comment: can you add other assemblies?! typically the tab '.NET' does not contain the file extension for its assemblies (so it would be System.Management assembly you need to add in the .NET-tab)

Comment: Fixed and working, there was a problem with VS, just restarted the program and all is working.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Don't Forget to write **using System.Management;** after adding the reference some time this happens even after adding the respective assembly it shows the error.

Comment: This mostly auto comes with visual studio main problem was covered by above 2 answers.